# Getting 3D vertex coordinate to image pixel coordinate

Tags: image

I have a .obj file obtained from the 3D model of a face image. The .obj file contains the 3D coordinates of each vertex, and the 3D surface normal at each vertex. My question is is it possible to obtain the pixel coordinates of these vertex coordinates so that I can have the knowledge of which normal is at which pixel coordinates, and I want to store the pixel coordinates in a text file. I am new to blender, and have no idea how to proceed with blender python script. I know there are some answers regarding 3D coordinates to 2D coordinates conversion, but I am not able to use those concepts in my problem. Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you open the OBJ file in a texteditor, you'll see all of your verts and their coordinates. Also, do you maybe want to UV-unwrap you mesh
( https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Textures/Mapping/UV/Unwrapping ) ?

Comment: Why are you unable to use the 3D to 2D conversion scripts?

Comment: @RayMairlot 3D to 2D conversion would directly provide me the pixel coordinate of the vertices?

Comment: @Reaper Yeah I can see the 3D coordinate of the vertices and the surface normals also. But I want the pixel coordinate of these vertices.

Comment: May i ask why? (Just for my interest^^)

Comment: Because I want to know pixel coordinate of the surface normals. Then using the pixel value (intensity) and the surface normal of that pixel I would like to estimate the lighting direction.